# python .write(raw_input('>')) works but next command line says "None"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python, and a novice at coding.  I haven't found a specific answer to this question but I'm sure it's very simple.

I am able to open a file in 'r+' mode and write a string to it based on raw input.  It works well and the raw input it written to the file, however the next line on the command line automatically returns the word "None".

Here is my code

> print txt.read()
>
> print "Please enter some text to add to the file:"
>
> print txt.write(raw_input('>'))
>
> print "Thanks"

And here is the return

> Please enter some text to add to the file:
>
> Here's some text from 11:26 am
>
> None
>
> Thanks

How can I get rid of this "None" output, and what is causing it? I've been searching for a return-argument but I can't figure out what to do.

Also, how can I get the raw input string to be on a new line of the document I'm writing to?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you all for helping to educate this n00b. I promise to return in kind when I become a more advanced programmer. Until then I'll be scouring this resource for previously answered questions and asking again for anything I can't find. Cheers 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer - remove `print` from 3rd line.

Your `txt.write(raw_input('>'))` writes to a file and doesn't return anything which is represented by None.

If you write your own function without return same would happen:

```
def test():
    print 'None appears below me'

print test()
#None appears below me
#None
```

In this case you just need to call it, and it will print:

```
test()
#None appears below me
```

Same goes for `write()` method.

For newline use `txt.write(raw_input('>') + '\n')`

Answer (score 0):

When you do `txt.write(raw_input(">"))`, your code writes the input to the file, correct. However, the function doesn't `return` anything - it doesn't need to. It's one of those functions that just does stuff on its own in place.

To get rid of it, just don't print it!

Comment: Thank you! So then I can just write txt.write(raw_input('>')) and that will be sufficient?

Comment: @Hanzy Correct!

Comment: Thanks so much! Just to expand, how can I get the raw input string to be on a new line of the file to which  I'm writing?

Comment: @Hanzy I assumed `file.write()` would automatically add the new line... but if not... just do `raw_input(...) + '\n'`.

Answer (score 0):

remove `print` from `print txt.write(raw_input('> '))`. The reason it prints `None` is because the builtin `file.write()` does not return anything, it just writes to a file. if you want to see the input that is entered by the user, do this:

```
text=raw_input('Enter some text to add to the file > ')
print text
txt.write(text)
print 'Thanks'
```

Answer (score 0):

python 2.7   no return

help(f.write)
Help on built-in function write:

write(...)
    write(str) -> None.  Write string str to file.

```
Note that due to buffering, flush() or close() may be needed before
the file on disk reflects the data written.
```

python3.5

help(f.write)
Help on built-in function write:

write(text, /) method of _io.TextIOWrapper instance
    Write string to stream.
    Returns the number of characters written (which is always equal to
    the length of the string).